# Getting the filename that contains http body from uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I have a background upload task that is defined in the following manner:

`NSURLSessionUploadTask* task = [session_ uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:httpBody]];`

I would like to delete`httpBody` once the upload task is finished, which happens in my delegate in this function:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    Q_UNUSED(session);
    if (error)
    {
        reportError(callback, error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableData *responseData = self.responsesData[@(task.taskIdentifier)];
        if (responseData)
        {
            NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
            if (response)
            {
                LOG_INFO << [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", response];
            } 
            else
            {
                LOG_INFO << [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            }
        [self.responsesData removeObjectForKey:@(task.taskIdentifier)];
        }
        (*callback)(boost::none);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to access `httpBody` in `didCompleteWithError` so I can delete it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get back the `originalRequest` from the task. If there is nothing in there to use, you can create the request as an NSMutableRequest to start and use:

```
+ (void)setProperty:(id)value 
         forKey:(NSString *)key 
      inRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request;
```

To add your filename to it. You can get this later with:

```
+ (id)propertyForKey:(NSString *)key 
       inRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
```

More info:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlprotocol/1407897-setproperty?language=objc

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try it now and will let you know if it works out.
I come from a C++ background and I am kind of new to objective-c(++).

Comment: Is there a special reason not to add the filename as part of the http header? 

Something like this for storing the filename:
`[request setValue:httpBody forHTTPHeaderField:@"httpBodyFile"]`

And something like this for retrieving:
`[task.originalRequest valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"httpBodyFile”]`

The reason is that I do not know how to properly subclass from `NSURLProtocol` or `NSMutableURLRequest` or whatever the appropriate class is.

Comment: Your made up headers should start with x-appname- to not interfere with other headers

Comment: How do you get the filename, i.e. `httpBody`, in `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`? I am assuming that this is called when background transfer is finished. This might be its own question.

Comment: task.originalRequest should have it

Comment: The signature does not include a `NSURLSessionTask` as an argument. It is `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler`

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676352/urlsessiondidfinisheventsforbackgroundurlsession-not-calling-objective-c -- you have to get the session back, then you can get tasks.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Can you recommend a resource for reading about background transfer? Apple’s documentation is not exactly descriptive when it comes to details.