# How to close an NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I am running an app that is continually looking for data from a server. I am creating a nsurlsession with datataskwithrequest and completionhandler. I repeat the request every thirty seconds. The problem is that after a certain amount of time, I am geting a dnssd_clientstub Connect to server: socket failed 24 to many open files. I think I need to close each session after I get a response with or without data or use the same session over and over again. I am looking for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest you don’t constantly reinstantiate new `NSURLSession` objects, and instead make sure you re-use your existing instance.

If you absolutely need separate `NSURLSession` instances, you can clean up prior ones with [`finishTasksAndInvalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1407428-finishtasksandinvalidate?language=objc). I think it’s better to use single instance, but this is one way to clean up your old instances if you absolutely need to have separate ones.

---

BTW, you might consider a different network pattern, namely socket-based solution. Then, rather than being like Bart Simpson in the back seat of the car, repeatedly asking “are we there yet?”, you can have your server tell your client when there’s something the client needs to be informed about. It’s a radically different approach, but is much better than polling every 30 seconds. If you don’t want to roll your own sockets-based solution, frameworks like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and [Realm](https://realm.io/) provide this sort of realtime interaction.

Or, if you really want to use your own server and you’re not ready to make the jump to sockets (or if you have no control over the server’s [RESTful](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) interface), consider having your server initiate a push notification when there is data for the client. It isn’t as reliable, but still better than polling every 30 seconds. Push notifications also has the virtue that the server can tell your clients when there is data to be retrieved even when the app isn’t running and the user can choose whether to fire up the app (or the app can fetch the data in the background so that if and when the user does fire it up, the data is already there).

Comment: Rob could you point me to an example of how to reuse an instance of an NSUrlSession

Comment: Well, [`[NSURLSession sharedSession]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1409000-sharedsession?language=objc) for one. Or you might have some manager/service object which you use to initiate your requests (e.g. like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32676536/1271826; that’s a delegate-based approach necessary for background sessions, but the general idea works for [`defaultSessionConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411560-defaultsessionconfiguration?language=objc) configurations, too).

Comment: Rob let me give you a little more information. The way i have it set now is I create an NSURLSession and within that session i create four tasks. Each task is performing a different url request to the same web service that returns different data.  I am using a dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:  for the four tasks. I have a finishtasksandinvalidate at the end of the last task before the resume.

Comment: So, the next time you do it, you create another `NSURLSession` and four requests? Why another `NSURLSession` each time? Why not use the same `NSURLSession`?

Comment: And, btw, do you start the next batch of requests 30 seconds after all four requests of the prior one finish or do you just have a 30 second repeating timer? You want to let the prior ones finish before you repeat the process. They could take more than 30 seconds to finish and you can easily run into problems if you don’t let them finish before the prior ones finish.

Comment: Rob you are correct that the best way would be to create one session but I am trying to work within an existing project without making a great deal of changes. I did fix the problem though. The issue was the NSTimer. I was creating a new timer each time and that was causing the app to send a bunch of messages at one time and overloading the system. I wrapped the timer in a conditional and it seems to have fixed my issue. Thank you for the help. I gave you an upvote but I do not have enough prestige for it to register, but I do appreciate the help.